# Allow user to select a full date with hours, but no minutes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have a requirement where the user should be able to pick date from the calendar. I have used the `<p:calendar>` of PrimeFaces.

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

The problem is that the user shouldn't be able to select **minutes**. He should be able to select only the hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide them with css

Like that

```
.ui_tpicker_minute_label{
    display:none;
}

.ui_tpicker_minute{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH"    it work

Comment: Can you please format and elaborate your answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:calendar  showOn="button"  id="idCalendar" value="#{managedBean.date}" navigator="true" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH">
                            <f:validateBean disabled="true" />
                        </p:calendar>
```

With this code you get the calendar only with the date and hour